# Update a table with composite key using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, composite-key

I am badly stuck in a table with a composite key. I am trying to use the eloquent to filter the record by two primary keys. But I came to know that eloquent doesn't support composite keys. I have gone through many solutions but no solution is clear enough for a beginner to understand.

a solution code says to edit the model class with the following code:

```
<?php
class CustomerAddress extends Model {
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
    {
        $query
            ->where('Customer_No', '=', $this->getAttribute('Customer_No'))
            ->where('Address_Name', '=', $this->getAttribute('Address_Name'));
        return $query;
    }

}
```

I want to perform the update function using the resource controller provided by laravel:
my code looks like this:

```
  /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $sem_course_id, $clo_id)
    {
        $id = $this->getKeyForSaveQuery();
        $request->validate([

            'assignments_weightage'=>'required',
            'quizes_weightage'=>'required',
            'project_weightage'=>'required',
            'class_participation_weightage'=>'required',
            'mid_weightage'=>'required',
            'final_weightage'=>'required',


        ]);

        $course = CoursesMarksScheme::find($clo_id,$sem_course_id); 
        $course->assignments_weightage =  $request->get('assignments_weightage');
        $course->quizes_weightage =  $request->get('quizes_weightage');
        $course->project_weightage = $request->get('project_weightage');
        $course->class_participation_weightage = $request->get('class_participation_weightage');
        $course->mid_weightage =  $request->get('mid_weightage');
        $course->final_weightage = $request->get('final_weightage');
        $course->save();

        return redirect('/coursesmarks');
    }
```

Also, please guide me on how to use the resource controller with primary keys as it is throwing an error for a few arguments?
Please help me. I am really exhausted reading a lot of online articles but unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: Did you try to update your model with the code?

Answer (score 0):

As I see solution code which you found is only for update, but don't for find. Laravel support composite key in migrations, but don't in eloquent.

Maybe it is better, use simple solution like this and don't waste time:

```
CoursesMarksScheme::where(['clo_id' => $clo_id, 'sem_course_id' => $sem_course_id])
    ->update($request);
```

I suppose necessary fields are in $fillable variable in CoursesMarksScheme model.

Comment: it is giving me an error that two few arguments to the function, How to deal with it? I am using laravel resource controller!

Comment: Is there any other way to get both the key values?

Comment: As I see you receive error, because of this CoursesMarksScheme::find($clo_id,$sem_course_id).

Comment: Try my solution.

Comment: What to mention in the eloquent as the primary key?

Comment: Nothing. Don't use find() method for composite key. Just use like this where(['clo_id' => $clo_id, 'sem_course_id' => $sem_course_id])->first() or where(['clo_id' => $clo_id, 'sem_course_id' => $sem_course_id])->update($data).

Comment: Still getting the error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CourseCloController::edit(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204286/discussion-between-g-baghashvili-and-rehan).

Comment: Write me in chat